# Broken xaml file after rebooting pc

Tags: file, xaml, ide, data-recovery

After rebooting my PC with opened VIsual Studio, all opened xaml files becomes invalid. Opening in different editors did not bring results. Is there any way to recover them ?

Comment: Why are they invalid? Do you get an error message? Have you tried getting a previous version from your local friendly source control?

Comment: I have no ideas. When i open that files in notepad ++ i see very long line like
nullnullnul.......  etc. But length is same like it was in original file.